# Remove interval double quotes in a CSV separated by comma and encapsulated by double quotes

Tags: linux, sed, csv

Perhaps I'm out of luck, because my double quoted comma separated CSV file has double quotes and commas within useful text.

So I want to turn this:

```
"record 1","name 1","text 1, text 2"
"record 2","name ""2""","text 2"
"record 3","name 3",""
```

on that:

```
"record 1","name 1","text 1, text 2"
"record 2","name 2","text 2"
"record 3","name 3",""
```

Notice that I removed the double quote from `name ""2""` to `name 2`, but I kept the double quote from line #3: `,""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `csvformat` to turn the delimiters to tabs (`csvformat -T`), removing any double quotes (`tr -d '"'`), and then returning the delimiters to commas while quoting every field (that last bit of the pipeline):

```
$ csvformat -T file.csv | tr -d '"' | csvformat -t -U1
"record 1","name 1","text 1, text 2"
"record 2","name 2","text 2"
"record 3","name 3",""
```

`csvformat` is part of [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Yes, [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the tool for that. Trying to parse csv with regular expressions is possible, but too complicated and error prone.

Comment: That'd fail if any of the fields contained tabs, it's just changing the problem from handling `,`s in the fields to handling `\t`s in the fields, not solving the problem.

Comment: @EdMorton You would easily be able to change the intermediate delimiter to any single character that is not part of the data, such as `@`, `#` or anything else. I chose tabs because `cvsformat` has a shorthand option for it, and because the given data did not contain any tabs. To use `@` instead, use `-D @` (instead of `-T`) with the first `csvformat` and `-d @` (instead of `-t`) with the second.

Comment: Picking any char that you hope won't be in the data is always a bit risky, especially if you don't have anything to warn you if it IS in the data. You could do something like `sed 's/@/@A/g; s/=/@B/g; s/,/=/g' file.csv | stuff | sed 's/=/,/g; s/@B/=/g; s/@A/@/g'` so you KNOW there are no commas (or whatever char you like) in your data while processing with `stuff`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708616/1745001 for what that pair of sed commands do.

Comment: Ignore that 2-seds suggestion as it'd remove the field-separating commas too. It's a good solution to a different problem :-).

Answer (score 0):

This will work no matter which characters are in your input (except newlines within quoted fields but that's a whole other problem).

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='("[^"]*")+' -v OFS='","' '{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        gsub(/"/,"",$i)
    }
    print "\"" $0 "\""
}' file
"record 1","name 1","text 1, text 2"
"record 2","name 2","text 2"
"record 3","name 3",""
```

or the equivalent with any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS='","' '{
    orig=$0; $0=""; i=0;
    while ( match(orig,/("[^"]*")+/) ) {
        $(++i) = substr(orig,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/"/,"",$i)
        orig = substr(orig,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print "\"" $0 "\""
}' file
"record 1","name 1","text 1, text 2"
"record 2","name 2","text 2"
"record 3","name 3",""
```

See also [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).